# How to retrieve top 3 highest and 3 lowest values in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I created a table as shown below,

```
CREATE TABLE SALES
(
       SALE_ID          INTEGER,
       PRODUCT_ID       INTEGER,
       YEAR             INTEGER,
       QUANTITY         INTEGER,
       PRICE                INTEGER
);
```

Now i want query which retrieves three highest and three lowest price products in the sales table. I am new in SQL please help. I tried a lot of queries but nothing happen. below is my query.

```
SELECT TOP 3 PRICE FROM SALES
Union 
SELECT PRICE FROM SALES order by PRICE;
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! You should always include your version of SQL Server (or whatever your RDBMS - or other system) is - the answers can frequently depend on these.

Comment: I edited my answer to deal with ties - check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use something like this (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=08901230e7a79c623754b1243ce11c69)) - it's perhaps more flexible than the other answer - in any case, you should look at learning [window functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/) in SQL - they can be very powerful.

First, table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE sale
(
  SALE_ID          VARCHAR (10),
  PRODUCT_ID       INTEGER,
  YEAR             INTEGER,
  QUANTITY         INTEGER,
  PRICE                INTEGER
);
```

```
INSERT INTO sale (sale_id, price) VALUES 
('Item_1', 1), ('Item_2', 2), ('Item_3', 3), ('Item_4', 4), ('Item_5', 5), ('Item_6', 6), 
('Item_7', 7), ('Item_8', 8), ('Item_9', 9), ('Item_10', 10), ('Item_11', 11), 
('Item_12', 12), ('Item_13', 13), ('Item_14', 14);
```

Run this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  t.sale_id, 
  t.price, 
  CASE 
    WHEN t.rn_up <= 3 THEN 'Low priced' 
    WHEN t.rn_down <= 3 THEN 'High priced'
  END as price_range
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    s.sale_id,
    s.price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.price ASC) AS rn_up,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.price DESC) AS rn_down
  FROM sale s
) AS t
WHERE t.rn_up <= 3 OR t.rn_down <= 3
ORDER BY t.price ASC;
```

Result:

```
sale_id price     price_range
Item_1      1      Low priced
Item_2      2      Low priced
Item_3      3      Low priced
Item_12    12     High priced
Item_13    13     High priced
Item_14    14     High priced
6 rows
```

If you want to deal with ties - I've added a record:

```
INSERT INTO sale (sale_id, price) VALUES  ('Item_43', 13);
```

And now, the results are (more or less) arbitrary - I run the same query and I get the same results - I reckon it may be the `INSERT`ion order of records that have a price of 13 (see the fiddle).

What you can do then is use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-dense_rank-function/) as follows:

```
SELECT 
  t.sale_id, 
  t.price, 
  CASE 
    WHEN t.rn_up <= 3 THEN 'Low priced' 
    WHEN t.rn_down <= 3 THEN 'High priced'
  END as price_range
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    s.sale_id,
    s.price,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s.price ASC) AS rn_up,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s.price DESC) AS rn_down
  FROM sale s
) AS t
WHERE t.rn_up <= 3 OR t.rn_down <= 3
ORDER BY t.price ASC, sale_id;
```

Result:

```
sale_id price   price_range
 Item_1     1   Low priced
 Item_2     2   Low priced
 Item_3     3   Low priced
Item_12    12   High priced
Item_13    13   High priced    --  <<=== Note: now we have 2 items with price 13!
Item_43    13   High priced
Item_14    14   High priced
```

As mentioned in comments, what exact SQL statement you'll use will depend on your  requirements  - I would just urge you to spend some time studying window functions - they'll repay that time ten times over!

Answer (score 2):

simplest:

```
select * from (select top 3 * from Sales order by Price asc) as firstThree
union 
select * from (select top 3 * from Sales order by Price desc) as lastThree
```